# Debugging jquery exception with Firebug

Tags: jquery, firebug

I am receiving a javascript error whose source line is in the jquery javascript library:

*`uncaught exception: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: #`*

I know what this error is: it usually happens if you try something like:

```
$('#');
```

However, I am struggling to debug it. It should be straightforward if I could just get a stack-trace. But Firebug refuses to either break-on-error or provide a stack trace.

I have tried clicking the "Break on error" button which is at the top left of Firebug's Console pane. I have also selected "Show Stack Trace with Errors" under the Console menu. But the exception still gets outputted without breaking and without a stack trace. Is there some other option in Firebug I could use... any tricks for debugging this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the development version of the jQuery library. In the jQuery function, add a console.log call to whatever selector was passed in. When you get your exception, the list of printed selectors should let you figure out where your code is going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

For debugging try:

```
console.log("#");
```

or

```
console.trace();
```

It will output stack traces into the FB console.

I think the problem is that you are trying to select an empty ID ("#") which throws the error. Jquery is probably parsing/looking for the id of "", which is an empty string using css selectors.

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [Javascript Stacktrace](https://github.com/eriwen/javascript-stacktrace) tool (there's even a bookmarklet version). You might also try the debuggers built into Safari or Chrome... unless of course your problem is specific to Firefox.